# Qual a diferença entre "notice" e "warning" no PHP?

Tags: php

Sempre vejo programadores dizendo : "Ah se fizer isso receberá um `notice`, mas se fizer isso recebe um `warning`", então me surgiu a dívida :

Qual a diferença entre eles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No PHP existem quatro tipos de erros "*comuns*":

- Parse Error/Syntax Error
- Fatal Error
- Warning Error
- Notice Error

---

**Parse Error**:

O *Parse Error* é provocado quando possui um código literalmente está quebrado, com erros de sintaxe, por exemplo sem o `;` no final de alguma linha ou com `{}` faltando, por exemplo:

```
<?php

$mensagem = 'uma coisa'

if(strlen($mensagem) > 10){
}
```

No caso seria esperado um `;` ao final do `'uma coisa'`, o resultado é este "*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)*".

O *Parse Error* impede que o seu código funcione desde de o inicio, simplesmente não irá funcionar nada.

---

**Fatal Error**:

O *Fatal Error* é quando o código não possui erros de sintaxe, porém ele não pode ser executado por alguma razão. Uma das razões principais é quando tenta chamar uma função inexistente, por exemplo:

```
echo funcao_inexistente();
```

Essa situação tudo está "ok", não tem erro de sintaxe, o problema é que não existe a função `funcao_inexistente();`, é impossível de executar o `echo funcao_inexistente();`, resultando em "*Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function funcao_inexistente();*"

Uma ressalva é que seu código pode funcionar até que a função inexistente seja chamada, por exemplo:

```
echo 'Antes do IF';

if( random_int(0,1) ){
   funcao_inexistente(); 
}else{
   echo 'Aqui dá certo`;
}
```

Embora a `funcao_inexistente()` não exista isso não faz diferença até que ela seja chamada. Você terá como resultado SEMPRE o `Antes do IF`. Além disso, você tem chances de receber um `Aqui dá certo` sem qualquer erro ou receber um erro fatal.

---

**Warning Error**:

O *Warning* é porque algo potencialmente está errado, mas o PHP ainda permite ele continuar. O mais famoso é o `Headers already sent`, mas para dar outro exemplo (e também comum) é não informar todos os argumentos/parâmetros da função:

```
function funcao($s, $i){
    return 'texto';
}

echo funcao('aaa');
```

O PHP por padrão não retornará um erro por não informar o `$i`, mas retornará um *Warning*, "*Missing argument 2 for funcao()*" para informar que algo esta fora o esperado, mas ainda é capaz de prosseguir.

> Caso utilize `funcao(string $s, string $i){}` passaria a retornar um *Fatal Error* caso o tipo especificado não correspondesse ao que está definido!

---

**Notice Error**:

Este é de longe o mais comum de todos os outros tipos. Normalmente ele indica que uma variável, array, constante não pode ser acessada. Porém, implicitamente se ele está ali é porque algo não está sendo tratado corretamente, por exemplo:

```
<form>
<input name="usuario">
<!-- .... -->
</form>
```

Você teria a crença única que o `usuario` fosse uma *string*, porém pode ser que envie um *array*, (`usuario['muito_louco']=valor`), logo:

```
echo $_POST['usuario'];
```

Vai emitir um "*Notice: Array to string conversion*". Além disso pode nem sequer existe o `usuario` então gerando um "*Notice: Undefined index*".

O `Notice` por si indica um problema maior do que ele mesmo, se é que pode dizer assim, normalmente se ele existe é porque algum dado entrou (ou saiu) de maneira que não era prevista pelo o seu sistema. Porém, para o PHP, o seu código seria capaz de suportar isto sem danos.

---

*Obviamente existem outros tipos de erros, como o `Deprecated`, por exemplo.*

Answer (score 9):

Um `notice` é um aviso que significa que *provavelmente* você não deveria estar fazendo o que está fazendo, mas vou permitir mesmo assim.

Um `warning` é uma mensagem informando que você *está* fazendo algo errado e é provável que isto causará erros, é melhor você corrigir!

Ambos não vão parar a execução do script, mas é melhor analisar e corrigir para não ter nenhum warning nem notice na sua aplicação.

Fonte: [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4624505/2312615).

Answer (score 9):

Embora possa não parecer, *warning* é um erro. É algo que não impede a execução do código, pode eventualmente produzir o resultado esperado, mas não deveria ser feito daquela forma. Deve ser tratado como erro.

Já o *notice* é uma informação que pode ser útil o programador dar uma avaliada se precisa melhorar alguma coisa ali, normalmente precisa.

Somente programadores XGH ignoram *warnings* e não fazem pelo menos uma investigação nos *notices*.

A titulo de curiosidade já peguei um software de 120 mil linhas que tinham mais de 600 mil *warnings*. Isto é trágico, o software funcionava por pura coincidência, você mexia em alguma coisa começava dar problema no software inteiro.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: "Embora possa não parecer warning é um erro.", isso é uma ironia?

Comment: @MagicHat por que seria?

Comment: Ah penso que um alerta tem uma relação direta com o erro, então não há porquê não parecer.

Answer (score 7):

Uma das coisas que mudam é o valor da constante, 2 para warning e 8 para notice. Basicamente são 'niveis de informações' diferentes. Indicam que o código executa alguma instrução que eventualmente pode gerar um erro e parar o script.

O interpretador diz algo como "olha essa instrução está estranha, por favor verifique se é isso mesmo que você deseja programador".

Retirado do [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)

Warning:

> 2 - Run-time warnings (non-fatal errors). Execution of the script is not halted.

Notice:

> 8 -    Run-time notices. Indicate that the script encountered something that could indicate an error, but could also happen in the normal course of running a script.

Comment: A que constante você se refere?

Comment: @MagicHat a que está no link da resposta no caso o 2 e o 8.

Comment: Hummm....`Errors and Logging`....ok...tks