# Erro no captcha

Tags: php, captcha

Estou com o seguinte erro no captcha:

> Notice: Undefined index: captcha in C:\xampp\htdocs\darknetwork\index.php on >line 7

e também ele só esta me retornando o else mesmo se der um F5 na page, o `session_start();` já esta no config.php

- index.php

  ```
  <?php
  require 'config.php';
  require 'classes/usuarios.class.php';
  $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

  $u = new Usuarios;
  if($_SESSION['captcha'] == $_POST['captcha']) {

    if(isset($_POST['email']) and !empty($_POST['email'])) {
      $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
      $senha = addslashes($_POST['senha']);

    if($u->login($email, $senha)) {

      header("Location: central.php");

    } else {
    ?>

    <div align="center" class="alert alert-danger">
    E-mail e/ou Senha incorretos, tente novamente !
    </div>

    <?php
            }
        }
    } else {
    ?>

    <div align="center" class="alert alert-danger">
    Captcha esta incorreto !
    </div>
    <?php
    }
     ?>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>Dark Network</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="login-page">
    <div class="form">
    <div style="color:#fff;" class="h4">
        ÁREA DE LOGIN - DARK NETWORK
      </div>
      <form class="login-form" method="post">
        <hr>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required=""/>
        <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" required=""/><br/><br/>
        <img src="captcha.php" alt="Código captcha"/><br/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="captcha" placeholder="Digite o código" required=""/><br/>
        <button type="submit"><span>Entrar</span></button>
        <hr>
        <p class="message">Não é registrado ? <a href="cadastrar.php">Cadastre-se aqui.</a></p>
        <p style="color:#999;">Desenvolvido por: Weltec</p>
      </form>
  </div>
  ```

  `
- captcha.php

  ```
  <?php
  session_start();

  $codigoCaptcha = substr(md5(time().rand(0,999)), 0, 9);

  $_SESSION['captcha'] = $codigoCaptcha;

  $imagemCaptcha = imagecreatefrompng("fundocaptch.png");
  $fonteCaptcha = imageloadfont("anonymous.gdf");
  $corCaptcha = imagecolorallocate($imagemCaptcha, 0, 115, 50);

  imagestring($imagemCaptcha, $fonteCaptcha, 15, 5, $codigoCaptcha, $corCaptcha);
  imagepng($imagemCaptcha);
  imagedestroy($imagemCaptcha);
  ?>
  ```

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: captcha in C:\xampp\htdocs\darknetwork\index.php on >line 7` isso ocorre por que o php esta procurando um valor para a validação do seu captcha mesmo antes de você sequer digitar no formulario para resolver este problema coloque `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//codigo de validação aqui}` e tambem você tera que dar um name para o seu input de submit `<button type="submit" name="submit"><span>Entrar</span></button>`

Comment: outro detalhe sua validação está incorreta pois o seu `$_SESSION['captcha']` está guardando um valor em MD5 e o seu $_POST['captcha'] não quando os dois forem comparados nunca se validarão pois um sempre será diferente do outro mesmo que o usuario digite corretamente no formulario então você deve colorar dessa forma na linda de codigo `if($_SESSION['captcha'] == MD5($_POST['captcha'])) {`

Comment: mas eu recomendaria você utilizar o reCaptcha do google é mais robusto e mais seguro https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59952/como-implementar-recaptcha-do-google-no-meu-site

Answer (score 1):

Isso é um `notice` e não um bem `erro` para saber a diferença veja o link citado pelo @Everson:

> [Qual a diferença entre "notice" e "warning" no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186344/3635)

**No entanto**, mesmo sendo um *notice* o ideal é checar se o envio foi feito por POST, pode usar `isset`, `empty` ou `filter_input`, note que o seu `if/else` estão sendo executados a todo momento.

Detalhes importantes:

- Se usa `isset` ou `empty`
- `isset` pode ser usado com mais de um campo

um exemplo simples seria isto:

```
<?php
require 'config.php';
require 'classes/usuarios.class.php';
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

//Uma variavel para o erro
$erro = null;

$u = new Usuarios;

//Checa se todos campos vieram do form
if (isset($_POST['captcha'], $_POST['captcha'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['senha'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['captcha'] == $_POST['captcha']) {
        $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
        $senha = addslashes($_POST['senha']);

        if($u->login($email, $senha)) {

            header("Location: central.php");
            exit; //Isso impede de "baixar" o resto

        } else {
            $erro = 'E-mail e/ou Senha incorretos, tente novamente !';
        }
    } else {
        $erro = 'Captcha esta incorreto !';
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dark Network</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php if ($erro) { /*se $erro não for null então é exibido */ ?>

<div align="center" class="alert alert-danger"><?php $erro; ?></div>

<?php } ?>

<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
```

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186344/57801

Comment: @Everson corrigi, não era warn era notice o correto a dizer, obrigado. Devidos créditos a ti na resposta.